Registering Pandas "accessors" without repeating yourself
I would like to use the Pandas register_series_accessor and register_dataframe_accessor functions to "tack on" a large number of functions/features to both Series and DataFrame objects.  But I would like to do so in a way "doesn't repeat myself".
At least to my eye, the way Pandas itself implements accessors like pd.Series.str involves them writing lots of boilerplate...essentially writing a "core" function that actually does the work and then separately re-writing a method within the accessor class that then calls out to the core function.  I'd like to avoid that.
Say I have a collection of functions that operate on pd.Series objects (in reality, my functions are more interesting than this, and more numerous):
def mf_cumsum_plus_const(ser, const=0):
    """Docstring for cumsum_plus_const"""
    return ser.cumsum().add(const)


def mf_cumprod_plus_const(ser, const=0):
    """Docstring for cumprod_plus_const"""
    return ser.cumprod().add(const)

MYFUNC_LIST = [mf_cumsum_plus_const, mf_cumprod_plus_const]

I would like to do something like:
@pd.api.extensions.register_series_accessor('mf')
class MFSeriesAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

        for func in MYFUNC_LIST:
            self.tack_on_function(func)

    def tack_on_function(self, func):
        # SOME MAGIC GOES HERE

I'm looking for some help for what to write at the SOME MAGIC GOES HERE spot.  I think a first draft might look like:
def tack_on_function(self, func):
    new_name = '_'.join(func.__name__.split('_')[1:]) # just tidying up the prefixes

    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(self._obj, *args, **kwargs)

    inner.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    inner.__name__ = new_name
    
    setattr(self, new_name, inner)

This mostly works.  But I think this winds up with a "generic" function signature for ser.mf.cumsum_plus_const.  How can I (programatically) get the signature of that function to look right?
I also want to programmatically get things working for the pd.DataFrame versions of these functions.  I.e. I want to do something like:
@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor('mf')
class MFDataFrameAccessor:
    def __init__(self, pandas_obj):
        self._obj = pandas_obj

        for func in MYFUNC_LIST:
            self.tack_on_function(func)

    def tack_on_function(self, func):
        new_name = '_'.join(func.__name__.split('_')[1:]) # just tidying up the prefixes

        def inner(*args, **kwargs, axis=0):
            # note that this is doing `pd.DataFrame.apply`
            return self._obj.apply(func, axis=axis, *args, **kwargs)

        inner.__doc__ = func.__doc__
        inner.__name__ = new_name
    
        setattr(self, new_name, inner)

So to get the DataFrame case working right, I'd need to find a way to set the signature of inner not to exactly match the signature of func (as I want to do in the Series case) but, instead to "match the signature of func but also include the extra keyword argument axis".
What's the right/best way to do this (in both the Series and DataFrame cases)?

Here is an example how you can construct the accessors for pd.Series and pd.Dataframe from list of functions:
from functools import partial


def mf_cumsum_plus_const(ser, const=0):
    """Docstring for cumsum_plus_const"""
    return ser.cumsum().add(const)


def mf_cumprod_plus_const(ser, const=0):
    """Docstring for cumprod_plus_const"""
    return ser.cumprod().add(const)


MYFUNC_LIST = [mf_cumsum_plus_const, mf_cumprod_plus_const]


@pd.api.extensions.register_series_accessor("mf")
class MFSeriesAccessor:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj
        self._funcs = {
            f.__name__.split("_", maxsplit=1)[-1]: partial(f, self._obj)
            for f in MYFUNC_LIST
        }

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._funcs[name]


@pd.api.extensions.register_dataframe_accessor("mf")
class MFDataFrameAccessor:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

        def _build_lambda(f):
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._obj.apply(
                f, axis=kwargs.pop("axis", 0), args=args, **kwargs
            )

        self._funcs = {
            f.__name__.split("_", maxsplit=1)[-1]: _build_lambda(f) for f in MYFUNC_LIST
        }

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self._funcs[name]

Then (with example dataframe):
print(df)

print(df.Col1.mf.cumsum_plus_const(1000))
print(df.Col1.mf.cumprod_plus_const(10))

print(df.mf.cumsum_plus_const(1000))
print(df.mf.cumprod_plus_const(10))

print(df.mf.cumsum_plus_const(1000, axis=1))
print(df.mf.cumprod_plus_const(10, axis=1))

Prints:
# example df:
   Col1  Col2
0     1     2
1     3     4
2     5     6

# df.Col1.mf.cumsum_plus_const(1000)
0    1001
1    1004
2    1009
Name: Col1, dtype: int64

# df.Col1.mf.cumprod_plus_const(10)
0    11
1    13
2    25
Name: Col1, dtype: int64

# df.mf.cumsum_plus_const(1000)
   Col1  Col2
0  1001  1002
1  1004  1006
2  1009  1012

# df.mf.cumprod_plus_const(10)
   Col1  Col2
0    11    12
1    13    18
2    25    58

# df.mf.cumsum_plus_const(1000, axis=1)
   Col1  Col2
0  1001  1003
1  1003  1007
2  1005  1011

# df.mf.cumprod_plus_const(10, axis=1)
   Col1  Col2
0    11    12
1    13    22
2    15    40

